# I am trying to display a quote after typing author name in the textbox but for some reason it is not displaying anything. How should I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch

I am getting undefined when I type the author name in the text box and press the button to display the quote. It seems like my button and textbox are not linked together. How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quotes</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="getQuotes">Find Quotes (Type Author Name)</label><br>
<input type = "text" id="getQuotes" name="getQuotes" placeholder="Search" style="margin:10px" size="50"/><br />
<button id="FetchQuotes" onclick="getQuote()"  style="margin:10px">Fetch Quotes</button>

<p id="quotes"></p>

<p id="author"></p>

<script>
    async function getQuote() {
        //const author = Boolean(false);
        let url = 'https://jaw1042-motivate.azurewebsites.net/quote';
        let author = document.getElementById('getQuotes').value;
        if(author) {
            url = 'https://jaw1042-motivate.azurewebsites.net/quote?author= ';
            console.log(url + author);
        } else {
            console.log(url);
        }
        fetch(url)
            .then(async (response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log("Response code: " + response.status);
                } else if (response.status === 400) {
                    console.log("Unable to find any quotes by specified author: " + response.status);
                } else {
                    console.log("No quotes have been loaded: " + response.status);
                }
                const val = await response.json();
                console.log(val);
            }).then(data => {
            document.getElementById('quotes').value = data;
            document.getElementById('author').value = data;
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to get author name, you sholuld make this variable: `let author=document.getElementById('getQuotes').value`.

Comment: yea I am trying to do that but it is not working. I have edited my code so would you mind looking at it again please

Answer (score 1):

your `then` functions are not correct
in the direct result of the fetchAPI you can receive data and to use it you need to run `.json()` or `.text()` on it, you can't simply use that result or return it's value ( plus when you use return statement all your next codes will be unreachable)
after that you should not assign something to your `data` variable because it just has new Data fetched from backend, by assigning new value to data you're about to ruin new data

here is how your js should look

```
     function getQuote() {
       fetch("https://krv1022-motivate.azurewebsites.net/quote")         
         .then( res => res.text() )
         .then( data => {
             document.querySelector(".quote").value = data;
         }
       );
    }
```

I also provided a fiddle for it but it can't receive data because either your URL is not correct or there is CORS issues

==============================================

one thing that I just noticed, you are receiving Author's name from end user but you are not about to send it to backend!

so perhaps this code is more complete, I assume that you want to send data using GET method and backend wants the name of author to be named `getQuotes`

Comment: when I do that .value=data it gives me an "undefined" result and also it doesn't specify the author. I have edited my answer can you look at it please

Comment: try removing that ```async``` from your function because it's not necessary, yes you get an error because the element you are selecting is not an ```input``` element, it's a simple ```p``` tag and they do not have any ```.value``` property (only ```input``` , ```textarea``` and a few more tags have ```.value```) to insert your data inside your page you can use ```element.innerText``` OR ```element.innerHTML```

Comment: thank you that worked and now it's working perfectly fine